# ¿Cómo puedo lograr que el HTML se actulice y muestre que una tarea se realizó al hacer click sobre el botón?

Tags: javascript, html

He intentado de muchas maneras y mi poca experiencia no me ha dejado encontrar la solución.
Estoy realizando una ToDo List y lo que necesito lograr es que al hacer click en el botón id="botonCambia" amarillo (NO), este cambie a verde con el texto SI, para que visualmente el usuario note que su tarea ha sido realizada!
Gracias a todos de antemano!!!

Comparto el código...

```
const inputTarea = document.querySelector("#tareaInput")
const botonTarea = document.querySelector("#agregaTarea")
const tablaTareas = document.querySelector("#tareas")

const misTareas = []
let idTarea = 0 

function renderTodasLasTareas() {
    let html = ""
    for (let tarea of misTareas) {
        html += `<tr>
                    <th>${tarea.id}</th>
                    <td>${tarea.descripcion}</td>
                    <td id="botonCambia" class="miniBoton"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm" onclick="cambiaEstado(${tarea.id})">NO</button></td>
                </tr>`
    }
    tablaTareas.innerHTML = html 
}

botonTarea.addEventListener("click", () => {
    const nuevaTarea = inputTarea.value 
    if (nuevaTarea == "") { 
        alert("Por favor agregar una tarea")
        return
    }
    idTarea++
    misTareas.push({ id: idTarea, descripcion: nuevaTarea, completado: false})
    inputTarea.value = "" 
    renderTodasLasTareas()
})

function cambiaEstado(id) {
    console.log(id)
    let cambio = document.getElementById('botonCambia')
    const index = misTareas.findIndex(tarea => tarea.id == id)
    if (misTareas[index].completado == false){
        misTareas[index].completado = true
        cambio.innerHTML = 'SI' //ESTO FUNCIONA PERO NO SE MUESTRA
        console.log(cambio)
    }else{
        misTareas[index].completado = false
        cambio.innerHTML = 'NO'
    }
    renderTodasLasTareas()
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes cambiar la propiedad con innerHTML, incluso si necesitas algún cambio de estilos puedes usar style o cambiar la clase y quitarlas con classList.add('nombredelaclase') y classList.remove('nombredelaclase').

Te dejo un código simple que cambia el texto del botón y su color de fondo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Cambio del boton</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="agregaTarea" onClick="Cambio()">No</button>
    </div>
    <style type="text/css">
        button{
            width: 100px;
            padding: 5px;
            margin: 50px;
            background-color: red;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Cambio(){
            const botonTarea = document.querySelector("#agregaTarea");
            if (botonTarea.innerHTML == 'No') {
                botonTarea.innerHTML='Si';
                botonTarea.style.background='green';
            } else {
                botonTarea.innerHTML='No';
                botonTarea.style.background='red';
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Gracias me funcionó!